# Executing Java source file via check_output

Tags: java, python, output

I want to check the output of a Java file via Python. There is no input, and the output of the java file is either TRUE or FALSE.

It is not a jar, but a .class file. (therefore already compiled)

I know this command:

```
res = check_output(['java', '-jar', 'stuff.jar'], input=b'foo')
```

for jar files with input

The java file is in a parallel folder and called Main.java.

```
res = check_output(['java', '-jar', '../Subfolder/Main'])
if res=="TRUE":
   doSomething()
```

seems to be wrong.

Comment: at least you should show us some piece of code you are using to do it

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the class path is set correctly.

`java -cp . Main`

Comment: Oh, sorry; I might have written it wrong. The java file is already compiled and available as .class file.

Comment: I corrected that information in the question, thank you

Comment: How would this look like then? res = check_output(['java', '-cp .', '../Subfolder/Main']) seems to be invalid.

Comment: 'cp' and '.' are separate.  `res = check_output(['java', '-cp', '.', '../Subfolder/Main'])`